# My Docker is crashing in Windows 10 Enterprise - (Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable)

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-container

I am using a Windows 10 Enterprise edition system. I have installed version: 17.03.1-ce-rc1-win3 (10625) Channel: edge . The Docker machine was working fine until a few days back.  Few days back I had disable Hyper-V in my system to use Oracle Virtual box to use Kubernetes and as a fact when hyper-V is disabled Docker won't run so I turned it back on and now it's crashing all the time and I am getting the below error.

```
[16:24:15.562][NamedPipeServer][Error  ] Unable to execute Start: Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable    at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.ConnectToVsud(TaskCompletionSource`1 vmId)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
[16:24:15.599][CrashReport    ][Info   ] Preparing package to send with the diagnostics
```

I uninstalled and installed Docker again but no vain and still getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tries with different combination the below final steps took care of my issue and my docker is running again.

Steps taken to resolve the issue :-

1. Uninstalled Docker from my system and deleted the .docker and 'Virtual Hard  Disk' directory which usually has the mobyLinuXVM file.
2. Uninstalled Oracle virtual Box from my machine.
3. Restarted my system and went to BIOS and unchecked/disabled the Virtualization options and logged into my system to see if virtualization is disabled using command systemInfo in cmd prompt and it was disabled.
4. Restarted my system again and went to BIOS and checked/enabled the virtualization option and logged into my system and made the virtualization was enabled back.
5. Installed again the docker and it was a charm and it started running.

The above steps may sound lame but it worked.